# Cannot insert duplicate key row even when using MAX(id)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Very occasionally on a multi-user system with SQL Server 2008 R2 I am getting errors like "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.pages' with unique index 'UX_pages_pageid_siteid'. The duplicate key value is (141, 4385).". That index does indeed enforce uniqueness but this is a single statement that should guarantee uniqueness as far as I know:

```
INSERT INTO pages (pageid, siteid) 
    SELECT (SELECT ISNULL(CAST(MAX(ABS([pageid])) AS int), 1000) + 1 
    FROM pages 
    WHERE siteid = 4385), 4385;
```

I know this would be cleaner with an auto-incrementing identity but I can't change the schema.

The statement is executing inside `o_Connection.BeginTrans()` and the database has `is_read_committed_snapshot_on` = 1 which I suspect is involved but I cannot reproduce the problem (e.g. by amending [this blog](http://improve.dk/solving-deadlocks-through-locking-hints) with `INSERT INTO tblPapers (Url) SELECT MAX(url) + 'z' FROM tblPapers)` or find any explanation in locking documentation.

Is it really the case that the nested `SELECT` may provide out-of-date data even though it is in the same statement and so changing the code to be `FROM pages (UPDLOCK)` is the correct fix?

Comment: What datatype is `padeid`? And by the way, what result do you get when you run `SELECT ISNULL(CAST(MAX(ABS([pageid])) AS int), 1000)`?

Comment: pageid is int allowing nulls and the select happily returns an integer (150) at the moment.

Comment: With Sql Server 2012, you could probably solve this with a sequence.  I know your stuck on 2008R2 right now, just something to keep in mind in the future.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: This error is almost certainly a result of concurrency. This is one of the main reasons trying to roll your own identity is a problem. You say you can't change the schema so you are going to be stuck with this unless you get very creative or upgrade to a newer version of sql.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. We have now got this to occur on the test server every few tries but not when the `(UPDLOCK)` that Mark S. Rasmussen's blog suggests is included so are going with that for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not scalable but try

```
INSERT INTO pages with (tablock) (pageid, siteid) 
    SELECT (SELECT ISNULL(CAST(MAX(ABS([pageid])) AS int), 1000) + 1 
    FROM pages 
    WHERE siteid = 4385), 4385;
```

I just read the comments - if (UPDLOCK) workds then stay with that

Comment: Thanks; I'll accept this as the answer rather than adding my own.